# Brocade smooth reboot command

Tags: switch, brocade, cli

I am newbie regarding switches.
I have Brocade ICX 7250 and 7450. 
I would like to know, what is the command for smooth reboot of switch. I do not want to unplug power cable and lost configuration.
I had commands like: sysshutdown, fastboot, which will be good?

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save your running config, type

```
write mem
```

To restart your switch without pulling the power cable, type

```
reload
```

Comment: thank you, reload will not have impact on current configuration? Even I will before that save running config?

Comment: The 'wr mem' command copies the the running configuration to the startup configuration.  If you 'reload' without typing 'wr mem' first, any changes you made to the running config will be lost.